Should buying an Etrog from Israel take precedence over Chutz laarerz?
Is there an Inyan or Halacha to buy an etrog from Eretz Yisrael? Is there a מעלה of purchasing etrogim from Israel over other countries? Does it make a difference if the person asking this question is located inside or outside the land of Israel?

Yes.
The Aruch HaShulchan (after establishing that the Israeli esrogim were without concern of murkav whereas the Corfu esrogim were) concludes:

ולכן כל איש מישראל אשר נגע יראת ד' בלבו – לא יקח רק אתרוגי ארץ ישראל
Therefore, any Jew whose fear of God affects his heart shall take
only of Israeli esrogim.

He then adds:

ואיך לא נבוש ולא נכלם בדבר מצוה שנוכל לקיימה מפרי ארצנו הקדושה, ליטול
דווקא מארץ העמים? אוי לה לאותה בושה, אוי לה לאותה כלימה! ועל זה נאמר:
וימאסו בארץ חמדה.
And how can one not be ashamed and humiliated — regarding a mitzva which he is able to perform through fruit of our holy land — to intentionally take from other lands? Woe for such a shame! Woe for such a humiliation! Regarding this it states "And they despised the cherished land."

(He lived in Lithuania and was not limiting his rulings to those living in Israel.)

R. Yechiel Michel Epstein was a Rav of Novahrdok, now Novogrudok in Belarus. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novogrudok

It appears to be a machlokes depending on whether we have such a mesorah and the quality of that mesorah.
Halachipedia:

Many say that the etrogim from Eretz Yisrael have a good mesorah.
Avnei Nezer CM 415 the Etrogim from Eretz Yisrael are the best because
there were religious Jews living there the entire time of the exile,
but because they’re difficult to get, we use Korfu. Taharat Haetrogim
p. 298 cites this.
However, some claim that the etrogim from Eretz Yisrael have no mesora
since religious Jews didn’t live there for many years before and after
the Ramban (Taharat Haetrogim p. 299 quoting Sod Yesharim p. 356,
Horat Heter p. 5. He also cites a testimony from R’ Yakov of Karaz
that the minhag Yerushalayim was to use Korfu etrogim.).
However, others uphold the mesora of the etrogim from Israel. (Taharat
Haetrogim p. 300 quoting Rav Meir Auerbach author of Imrei Binah
(Nefesh Chaya OC 4). He also cites Rav Chaim Nissim Abulafia
supporting those etrogim.).


I think this answer misses the point entirely. Assuming you had a kosher species from both Israel and outside Israel, is there any reason to prefer the one from Israel?
